# Kommasetzung bei „intuitiv gesprochen“

Tags: comma

Ich habe mehrere Fragen.

1. Ist der folgende Satz hinsichtlich der Kommasetzung korrekt?

> Intuitiv gesprochen ist eine Funktion von A nach B eine Zuordnung, die jedem Element von A ein Element von B zuordnet.

2. Welche der folgenden Sätze ist hinsichtlich der Kommasetzung korrekt?

> a. Eine Funktion von A nach B ist**,** intuitiv gesprochen**,** eine Zuordnung, die jedem Element von A ein Element von B zuordnet.
>
> b. Eine Funktion von A nach B ist intuitiv gesprochen eine Zuordnung, die jedem Element von A ein Element von B zuordnet.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] dieser Seite nehmen. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Comment: Wie spricht man denn intuitiv?

Comment: @CarstenS Ich denke, man kann intuitiv sprechen, ich denke nur nicht, dass es im Beispiel richtig ist.

Comment: @CarstenS Intuitiv sprechen geht so: "Wie soll ich wissen, was ich denke, bevor ich höre, was ich sage?"

Comment: Das Hauptproblem ist nicht die Kommasetzung, sondern die unidiomatische Wortwahl, die so auch in mathematischen Fachtexten unüblich ist. Das ist kein Deutsch, sondern zu wörtlich übersetztes Englisch - wahrscheinlich deshalb, weil dict.leo.org für "intuitively" nichts Passendes anbietet. Mein Vorschlag: "sinngemäß".

Comment: @HansAdler "sinngemäß" ist gut, löst das Problem des Kommas aber nicht...

Comment: Als Informatiker muss ich übrigens ergänzen: "... jedem Element von A **genau ein** Element von B zuordnet." Der Unterschied ist klein, aber dennoch sehr wichtig.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Als Mathematiker würde ich je nach Kontext das *genau* hier schon in einer präzisen Definition als entbehrlich ansehen. In einer "intuitiven" Erklärung dann erst recht.

Comment: @tofro: Mit *sinngemäß* ist Jans Antwort im Prinzip immer noch passend, und man hat eine bessere Intuition dafür: Normalerweise eher ohne Komma, aber man kann es im Fall 2 auch setzen.

Comment: @HansAdler Als Mathematiker dürftest Du eigentlich das *genau* gar keines Falles als entbehrlich ansehen, schon gar nicht in einer präzisen Definition...

Comment: Wenn wir für jede Kleinigkeit so pedantisch wären, dann würden wir nie über den Beweis von Trivialitäten hinauskommen. Genau wie in der Alltagssprache wird auch in der Fachsprache common sense vorausgesetzt. Und hier braucht man noch nicht mal das, weil hier die Anzahl der zugeordneten Elemente angegeben wird - und zwar als 1 ("ein Element") und nicht als ≥1 ("mindestens ein Element").

Comment: Persönlich würde ich *intuitiv gesprochen* hier sogar mittels Gedankenstrichen abteilen, aber ich setze tendentiell auch eher mehr Satzzeichen. Korrekt sind dennoch beide Varianten.

Comment: @HansAdler Common Sense nimmt aber einer Wissenschaft, in der es auf präzise Definitionen ankommt, ihre Präzision. Nicht ohne Grund dürfte das *genau* in der Definition von "Funktion" enthalten sein, welche ich auf die Schnelle auftreiben konnte. Und spätestens wenn es um Aussagen wie "es ist Donnerstag oder meine Mutter kommt zu Besuch" geht, versagt der Common Sense meist bei dem Verständnis warum es möglich ist, dass die Mutter auch am Donnerstag zu Besuch kommt... Aber das ist hier off-topic.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Ich hab das nicht frei erfunden, sondern jahrelang in Forschung und Lehre gearbeitet. Der Vorwurf, die Mathematik wäre keine exakte Wissenschaft, nur weil sie praktisch immer mit Formulierungen operiert, die ohne Kontext oder bei absichtlich falscher Interpretation missverstanden werden könnten, ist mir bisher nicht untergekommen und dürfte eine Minderheitsmeinung sein. Nur in meinem Forschungsgebiet (Logik) muss man genauer sein, weil da mathematische Aussagen selbst Forschungsobjekte sind. Aber selbst da verwenden wir für konkrete Formeln keine unnötige Sorgfalt.

Comment: @HansAdler Ich sage ja auch nur, dass **jede** Definition von "Funktion", die mir untergekommen ist, das *genau* enthält. Vermutlich eben, um klarzustellen, dass *mindestens ein* explizit ausgeschlossen ist. Im Falle dieser Definition lasse ich mich meinetwegen auch bekehren, aber es gibt eben auch Fälle, wo die "mathematische" (häufig als kompliziert, lustig, übergenau, etc. belächelte) Sprache ihren Sinn hat, da mit natürlicher Sprache die gleiche Aussage nicht getroffen werden kann. Vielleicht bin ich als Informatiker da anders, da ich Kundenanforderungen umsetzen muss => Präzision wichtig.

Comment: Zwischen Programmierern mit meist unterschiedlichem Hintergrund und mehr noch im Kundenkontakt gibt es für die Kommunikation ganz andere Anforderungen. Da ist diese Art der Redundanz oft tatsächlich sinnvoll, weil sich sonst z.B. jemand sagen kann: Da steht "ein Element", aber es wird ja kein Problem sein, dass es manchmal zwei sind. Diese Gefahr der Fehlinterpretation besteht bei dieser Definition aber nicht. Wer Relationen und Multifunktionen kennt, weiß, dass sie was anderes sind, und wer sie nicht kennt, kommt erst gar nicht auf die Idee.

Answer (score 5):

Die Fragen sind im Prinzip ein- und dieselbe Frage. Es geht darum, ob »intuitiv gesprochen« durch Kommas abgetrennt werden darf, muss oder nicht darf.

Zunächst einmal ist herauszufinden, was »intuitiv gesprochen« in deinen Beispielsätzen ist. Ein Ganzsatz auf keinen Fall, ein normaler Nebensatz auch nicht: beide würden ein finites Verb benötigen. Es ist auch keine Infinitivgruppe, damit sind die §§ 71 mit 75 der [amtlichen deutschen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) nicht relevant. Eine Möglichkeit wäre, die Wortgruppe als formelhaften Nebensatz nach § 76 zu verstehen. Die amtlichen Beispiele sind:

> Wie bereits gesagt(,) verhält sich die Sache anders. Ich komme(,) wenn nötig(,) bei dir noch vorbei.

Dann wären die Kommas möglich, aber optional.

Eine andere Interpretationsmöglichkeit wäre ein Zusatz oder Nachtrag nach § 77. § 77(7) behandelt explizit Partizipkonstruktionen:

> [das betrifft] nachgetragene Partizip- oder Adjektivgruppen oder entsprechende Wortgruppen auch am Ende des Ganzsatzes (siehe auch § 78(3)).

Das würde für eine Kommapflicht in deinem Fall 2a sprechen. Allerdings gilt § 78:

> § 78: Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.

---

Zusammengefasst: § 77(7) kann sich nur auf deinen Fall 2 beziehen. In Verbindung mit § 78(3) sind die Kommas optional.

§ 76 kann man auf beide deiner Fälle anwenden. Auch dieser beschreibt alle Kommas als optional.

Demnach sind alle drei Varianten korrekt.